Как объяснить погрешность линейной регрессии?
Для обработки результатов одного эксперимента использую OLS из statsmodels.regression.linear_model.
Получил регрессионное уравнение при стандартных условиях опыта, затем ввожу дополнительные факторы в эти условия (некоторые факторы влияют на величину определяемой физической величины 'Y', некоторые нет)  и рассчитываю результат, определяя величину возможных погрешностей (знаю, что странно, но поставили на работе такую задачу). Погрешность нахожу относительно значения, рассчитанного по регрессионному уравнению для стандартных условий.
Все результаты прекрасно сходятся с предполагаемыми: если фактор заведомо влияет на условия (и на величины Y), то появляется большая погрешность, в ином случае (если фактор влияния не оказывает, Y значимо не меняется) погрешности сравнимы со случайными.
Однако в одном случае, когда фактор не должен влиять, получается большая погрешность в 18 %. В других аналогичных случаях с невлияющими факторами погрешность не более 4%, конкретно этот фактор абсолютно точно не влияет. Все Y тут меняются в гораздо меньшей степени, чем в случаях с маленькой погрешностью (изменения для Y являются незначимыми).
Примеры данных могу показать только на картинке: синий - результаты в стандартных условиях; зеленый - результаты с отрицательной погрешностью -1,6% (имеет случайный характер); красный - результаты с проблемным фактором (который не влияет, но дает дикую погрешность), погрешность 18%. Для сравнения желтым показано результаты с посторонним фактором, который заведомо влияет на результаты (погрешность -8,3%). Повтор эксперимента дает ту же ситуацию.
Для двух десятков других результатов без влияния каких-либо посторонних факторов расчеты верны (ошибка не более 4%). Уравнение работает хорошо.
Я знаю, что использование условий, отличных от тех, в которых получали данные для регрессионного уравнения, приводит к непрогнозируемым погрешностям. Проблема в том, что этот фактор, с которым возникает погрешность 18%, НЕ влияет на физическую величину и на ее измерение, т.е. такой погрешности не должно быть. Крайне необходимо объяснить, почему алгоритм ее выдает.

Ось Х - расстояние. Ось Y - некая физическая величина.

Нет, так не пойдёт, давайте примеры на числах прямо в вопросе. И код. А то вроде кажется понятно, о чём вы говорите, а вроде и нет. Лучше бы вообще все данные приложить, но если их нельзя выкладывать, то можно просто небольшие примеры привести, чтобы было понятно о чём собственно речь. Ещё бы хорошо картинки со стрелочками нарисовать, из эстетических соображений (и для ещё большей понятности). Ну и на самих данных я бы графики порисовал, из графиков бывает многое понятно.

Извините, но я и на картинке не понимаю, что вы нарисовали :(  На картинке должны быть подписи: заголовок, названия осей, названия серий точек. Чётко сформулированные условия задачи - это половина успеха. Если не 90%.

К сожалению, не имею возможности представить более подробные данные. Краткое описание дал в тексте, дублирую:
синий - стандартные условия, погрешность определения по регрессионному уравнению 2,7%; зеленый - отрицательная погрешность -1,6%; красный - проблемный фактор (который не влияет, но дает дикую погрешность), погрешность 18%. Для сравнения желтым показано влияние постороннего фактора, который заведомо влияет на результаты (погрешность -8,3%).
Могу добавить, что на оси Y некая физическая величина, на оси Х - расстояние.

Мне не понятно, что вы делаете. У вас в результате получаются какие-то числа, но откуда они взялись - мне не понятно. Что именно значит "ввожу дополнительные факторы"? "появляется большая погрешность" - как именно вы считаете погрешность? Что значит "фактор влияет на величины Х" (что вы тогда называете фактором, если не элементы Х?) Данные и программа , возможно, прояснили бы это, но если не можете их дать, то хотя бы объясните, что вы делаете на уровне формул.

Приблизительно я вроде понимаю, что X - это матрица с данными, там есть какие-то колонки, по которым строится регрессия. Если мы добавляем ещё какие-то колонки в X, то регрессия даёт результаты хуже. Так? Непонятно только, где именно вы меряете эти погрешности/ошибки. Строите регрессию на всех данных, а потом по отдельным точкам смотрите, что регрессия в них предсказывает? Если я всё правильно понял, то в принципе такое возможно, что добавление каких-то факторов в данные ухудшает качество модели. Но тут очень важно описать на какой части данных вы строите модель и на какой её проверяете.

В частности для регрессии очень плоха мультиколлинеарность данных, но вы пишете, что от этих "вредных" факторов ничего не зависит, значит это не мультиколлинеарность. Могут быть ещё просто случайные данные, из-за которых модель портится. Но такие данные легко выявляются с помощью кросс-валидации. Просто смотрим добавление каких факторов ухудшает скор на кросс-валидации, а каких улучшает и всё. В общем, без грамотной валидации тут тоже никуда. А вы ничего не объяснили - на чём вы модель тренируете и на чём проверяете. На каких подмножествах ваших данных вы это делаете.

Ситуация проясняется, но очень медленно. Ладно. Навскидку посоветую попробовать регуляризацию OLS.fit_regularized, и поиграйтесь там параметром L1_wt. А, ну и ещё statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model.RLM тоже попробуйте. Если же вам именно объяснить, почему у обычной линейной регрессии проблемы, то без объяснения, что вообще вы делаете тут никак. Хотя бы на каких данных вы качество регрессии проверяете. На тех же на каких учитесь или на других.

Благодарю за полезные советы!
